# How to convert date to milliseconds in runtime?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to convert date to milliseconds and query the result.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TableA WHERE DATE = '2017/09/24';
```

So I want to replace date '2017/09/24' to the milliseconds value and fetch data.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. When it comes to date/time most products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Sorry, I added the tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) From TableA WHERE Date BETWEEN unix_timestamp('2017-03-10 00:00:00') AND unix_timestamp('2017-03-10 00:00:00');
```

This worked in MySQl for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM TableA
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SSSSS') = '2017/09/24 10:10:86399';
```

Play with different date formats. Here is [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm)

PS: Sorry I replied for oracle DB.

Comment: SELECT count(*) From TableA WHERE Date BETWEEN unix_timestamp('2017-03-10 00:00:00') AND unix_timestamp('2017-03-10 00:00:00');   This worked in mysql.